# Как хранить пароль от БД в коде?

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных, jdbc

Недавно наткнулся на такую проблему, что не знаю как вписать пароль от БД в код на Java для использования JDBC. Как лучше всего хранить пароль от БД в коде, чтобы он не попал в чужие руки?

Comment: Очень просто — не хранить в коде вообще

Comment: В продолжение @andreymal, для хранения паролей, токенов, логинов и тд используй менеджеры секретов

Comment: тогда как хранить пароль и что такое менеджеры секретов?

Comment: Где угодно кроме кода - в файле, в переменной окружения, в том же менеджере секретов и так далее

Answer (score 0):

1. Можно хранить пароль в переменных окружения. Например, создайте файл Property, в который напишите параметры для jdbc. Выглядит он примерно так:

```
dataSourceClassName=org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
dataSource.user=${POSTGRESQL_USERNAME}
dataSource.password=${POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD}
dataSource.databaseName=database_name
dataSource.portNumber=5432
dataSource.serverName=localhost
```

Переменные окружения можно добавить разными способами. Зависит от вашей ОС. На macOS выглядит примерно так:
`export POSTGRESQL_USERNAME=neonik`

Еще раз, что необходимо сделать:

1. Создаем файлик database.properties
2. Заполняем его по примеру
3. Идем в настройки и заполняем переменные окружения
4. В jdbc отдаем нашу properties, либо самомстоятельно читаем из properties и кладем полученные поля в jdbc.
5. Радуемся, что наш пароль никто не узнает

Если что-то не получается, пользуемся гуглом.

2. Можно создать файлик по типу config.env или просто .env . В gitignore добавить этот файлик, чтобы он случайно не отправился в ваш гитхаб.
   Ну и в самом файлике просто пишем примерно такое содержимое:

```
user=neonik
password=our_password
```

Теперь осталось в коде написать парсер этого файла и передавать полученные данные в `JDBC`.

3. Если вы используете CI/CD. То там есть раздел секреты. Он конечно везде по-разному называется, но суть примерно такая же. Так это выглядит в Github Actions
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И уже в файликах для CI/CD прописываете эти секреты. Так это выглядит для github Actions:

```
      - name: Log in to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
```

Но третий пункт уже для будущего, я полагаю, что у вас еще нет настроенных CI/CD.